# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener;

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use Firebase for a simple CRUD android app, but while instantiation of a Firebase database reference, I encounter the following exception at runtime:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (3.0.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
    at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform$1$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:98)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    ....
    ....
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener;
    ....
    ....
    at com.satwick.employeecrud.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)
```

I went through StackOverflow, and although there have been many cases of NoClassDefFoundError in Firebase, none of them were about `IdTokenListener`. What I mainly realized is this might've been an error of missing some steps, while setting up the Firebase database. So I rechecked all steps:

1. Ensured my app is registered with the Firebase project, with correct signing SHA1.
2. google-services.json is included in my app directory.
3. firebase is correctly loaded in the application's and project's gradle files. (I can complete phone number authentication for now, so I'm pretty sure.)

In the onCreate() method:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
            List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build());

            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);
        } else {
            mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
        }

        // MainActivity.java:76 The following line causes the exception.
        mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 
    }
```

Is this a bug with Firebase? Or am I doing something wrong?
Please help.

Also, I don't know if this is related or not, but I have two applications registered with the same Firebase project, with the same signing key (Android Studio's default SHA1.)

EDIT 1 -
Adding dependencies {} of build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'

    // Google
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:17.0.0')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'

    // Firebase UI
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Could you post your app's `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was using some unwanted libraries in `build.gradle`, so cleared off the clutter to the following imports for Firebase:

```
// Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'

// Firebase UI
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:5.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:5.0.0'
```

Consequently, I tried updating the version of firebase-ui from 4.3.1 -> 5.0.0, and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I tried downgrading my version from

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:**4.3.1**' 
to 
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:**4.3.0**'

and

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:**19.2.0**' 
to
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:**16.0.4**'

and it worked